# Creating a series of RSA Public Keys in python

Tags: python, rsa

So I want to create a list of RSA public keys using the RSA generator in python, but I'm having some issues figuring out how to go about it. So far I have

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
key_pair = RSA.generate(2048)
public_key = key.publickey()
print public_key
```

But so far I see two issues. One is the output is odd, looking and has the form of an RSA Object where I just want the long form version of the key with a bunch of letters

Second is that if I run this code in a loop all the keys generated are the same.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your questions look quite basic. Take a look at the [documentation](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/doc/) and then retry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Addressing the first issue, you can call `public_key.exportKey()`:

```
>>> from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
>>> key_pair = RSA.generate(2048)
>>> public_key = key_pair.publickey()

>>> print(public_key.exportKey())
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAoGX9PTzmX+2AwMIhUunN
BUVPRpFFg63bLORKHEgHDW0RntE5u0yPB64Th4+zVas9yQBLhK+v2O6K4gyLOaT5
lQNF5KHQE3l/j6kInLIm73nMhdNJDpoV1cVUgTnuXoAEcTQXwYFf5ME/1/N4txIO
Toi1Z5T5eeVk2SXICdFL47l2vPpcVFmrNGZ16QrZDpVIo3aTmIllbwpm/YPsoLta
U3rcaMkEIar6y1iVEYVZCydN56YH4LDUpT7iGNFYAqgYGUkKHK/h7QATN21HAi/y
a51jrCOBCLCklcGU7/6x+2M5KhMbRRAN2/h1AH+CFdZ140Ml5a5mX+k2QPuplKwk
cwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

You can strip off the BEGIN header and END trailer by splitting the output and taking the inner lines:

```
>>> exported_key = public_key.exportKey().splitlines()[1:-1]
>>> print('\n'.join(exported_key))
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAoGX9PTzmX+2AwMIhUunN
BUVPRpFFg63bLORKHEgHDW0RntE5u0yPB64Th4+zVas9yQBLhK+v2O6K4gyLOaT5
lQNF5KHQE3l/j6kInLIm73nMhdNJDpoV1cVUgTnuXoAEcTQXwYFf5ME/1/N4txIO
Toi1Z5T5eeVk2SXICdFL47l2vPpcVFmrNGZ16QrZDpVIo3aTmIllbwpm/YPsoLta
U3rcaMkEIar6y1iVEYVZCydN56YH4LDUpT7iGNFYAqgYGUkKHK/h7QATN21HAi/y
a51jrCOBCLCklcGU7/6x+2M5KhMbRRAN2/h1AH+CFdZ140Ml5a5mX+k2QPuplKwk
cwIDAQAB
```

---

I am not able to replicate the second issue. A new key pair is generated each time `RSA.generate()` is called:

```
pub_keys = set()
for i in range(5):
    k = RSA.generate(2048).publickey().exportKey()
    assert k not in pub_keys
    pub_keys.add(k)
```

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. I think I have it figured out. Now this long form version of an RSA key, is that a hex representation of a large number? I'm just asking for clarity sake

Comment: @TomBald94: it is base64 encoded. You can get the original using `base64.decodestring()`.

Comment: So if I call `base64.decodestring` it will give me the original value, not including the part with --BEGIN PUBLIC KEY--

Comment: @TomBald94: No, just the part in between the header and trailer is base64 encoded. This is the "bunch of letters" that you wanted. If you want the binary representation you can base64 decode the relevant part of the key, or, easier, export the key in DER format: `public_key.exportKey('DER')`.

Comment: @TomBald94: Possibly an easier way is to export the key in DER format, and then base 64 encode that. This avoids the header and trailer lines: `base64.encodestring(public_key.exportKey('DER'))` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following code to generate an RSA keypair with an exponent of 65537 in PEM format.

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
new_key = RSA.generate(2048, e=65537)
public_key = new_key.publickey().exportKey("PEM")
print public_key
```

It will generate a public key for you as looks like following:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAp1rxDD3DyFAlZWUZhnT2
IrqXBx+XBgMRWYvOPoyjHwwBK/UlD6JW2cx2lP6TJ/Ljrpiamt35cfjRl8PROy81
hRRrVqa9AMUPcIkQoc9Y6VMxHURluX6AJOkakmszlwJvsHr5smMyG7oW/TpSBpR0
xNPc8lyGfhim8GuNomKaDkc5XhNHP7NWhpvOUbneqffkYExbRQrt1UrEMqRryxGh
Lk2rRB3Gny+iOFJP/AfDN0nxFFBrn32uD+2gDUBaBBta6Ii7+LbdpwUkXZlErFA9
5a7mE6g2Q4k87Pc0XwaxcLxwriejCtXD5cz0RgtkItkcUc/wU1vmnhol9Ncm6XSi
xwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Hope it helps!